# convert a 2d double array to a 2d int array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, copy

I want to convert a 2d double array to another 2D array of integers. The double array is filled with values lower than 1.  What I want to do is create a new int[][]array and, using a if else statement set the values in the new array to 1 and 0. I have posted my attempt but I am not sure where to initialize my int array which is called intMatrix.

```
public int[][] readCorrMatrix(){

    String filename=ReadFile.getPath();
    double[][]rawDataMatrix=ReadMatrix.readDataMatrix(filename, ",");
    RealMatrix speaRealMatrix=Spearmans.calcSpearMatrix(rawDataMatrix);
    double[][]speaRealMatrixArray=speaRealMatrix.getData();
    int[][]intMatrix=null;
    for(int i=0; i<speaRealMatrixArray.length;i++){
        for(int y=0; y<speaRealMatrixArray[i].length;y++){

            intMatrix[i][y]=(int)speaRealMatrixArray[i][y];
            if(speaRealMatrixArray[i][y]<0.6)
            {
                intMatrix[i][y]=0;
            }
                else
                {
                    intMatrix[i][y]=1;
                }               
        }
    }
    return intMatrix;
}
```

Do you guys have any idea as to what I am doing wrong.  Thanks in advance,
Jetnori.

Comment: Sorry forgive my mistype. I mean I want to convert a 2d double array to another 2d int array. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Mat, Will do. I try to reply to everyone to say thanks. I will definitely use follow your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[][]intMatrix= new int[speaRealMatrixArray.length][];
...
for(int i=0; i<speaRealMatrixArray.length;i++){
      intMatrix[i] = new new int[speaRealMatrixArray[i].length];
      for(int y=0; y<speaRealMatrixArray[i].length;y++){
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if is checking the wrong array.

intMatrix[i][y]=(int)speaRealMatrixArray[i][y]; will be always 0 if we assume that the values in the given matrix are < 1. And in the next line you check its value which must be 0 anyhow. Remove the assignment and check speaRealMatrixArray[i][y] < 0.6

Also you've got to initialize the int array correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize intMatrix properly.

Also instead of

```
intMatrix[i][y] = (int) speaRealMatrixArray[i][y];
if (intMatrix[i][y] < 0.6) {
    intMatrix[i][y] = 0;
} else {
    intMatrix[i][y] = 1;
}
```

try

```
if ( speaRealMatrixArray[i][y] < 0.6) {
    intMatrix[i][y] = 0;
} else {
    intMatrix[i][y] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It makes sense now. The statement above the if was no use at all.